# how to stop selenium click() waiting 30second on IE

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

I got a v problem while using selenium.click() in java.my code is

```
public void manageLeft1(int arg[]) throws Exception{
        selenium.click("name=checkboxgame");
        for(int i=1;i<8;i++){
            //block for test
            selenium.click("xpath=(//input[@name='list'])["+i+"]");
        }
        if(arg[0]>0&&arg.length<7){
            int memberNum=arg.length;
            for(int i=0;i<memberNum;i++){
                selenium.click("xpath=(//input[@name='list'])["+arg[i]+"]");
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is the click always wait 30 seconds,i've tried setTimeout already ,it's not working.
please help,thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I thought it was webdriver and selenium the driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to retrieve the element at first and then call the click()-Method.

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id("name=checkboxgame")).click();
```

So the click is only executed and no waiting happens.
On the other hand, you will get an Exception when the element doesn't exist.

Comment: yes,it works in webdriver! but how can i just use selenium rc to fix this problem by the way?